# watson chatbot dialog flow not hitting child node

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

[image: ibm dialog flow]

Please take a look at the images. The response that I am getting on IBM UI side is not showing in the Java console. It is empty or null, but the intent is hit correctly.

I am developing a chatbot using the `java watson conversation api`, but I am facing an error while hitting the child node. Is it a context issue or something else? I am not able to figure it out. I attached the code.

Please help.

input_gui is user input

```
MessageRequest newMessage = new 
MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(input_gui).context(context).build();
MessageResponse response = conversationService.message(workspaceId, newMessage).execute();

    newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder()
            .inputText(input_gui)
            .context(response.getContext()) // output context from the first message
            .build();
    System.out.println("watson response"+response);
```

Please look at image i am attaching. This image is .......

[image]

Comment: It really depends on how you built your Dialog flow. I am expecting from the message that you simply didn't match any of the available conditions, and don't have a fallback node with an always true condition.

Comment: in watson conversation service UI is showing response if i tried but in java code output is null is there any issue in java code related to context

Comment: Using punctiation marks would surely help

Comment: alex can you provide more detail where i have to use punctiation marks.

Comment: @5agado i added anything_else node at the last of dialog flow i found that only root node condition gets hit my code not able to find child node condition dialog counter not increasing to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code I got my error I called service credential every time so context get initialize on every input message that why I am not able to get single conversation id in conversation now it's working

```
MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(input).context(context).build();

MessageResponse response = service.message(WORKSPACE_ID,newMessage).execute();

context = response.getContext();

System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not one expert in Java but, trying to help you, check the [Java SDK examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/examples/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationExample.java) for Watson Conversation. You can check out this [project](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery) from IBM Developers, they are using Conversation Service with Java.

See the code that I did a few months ago for one test:

```
MessageRequest.Builder messageRequestBuilder = new MessageRequest.Builder();
        messageRequestBuilder.inputText(input_gui);
        messageRequestBuilder.context(question.context); //this context comes from a previous step 


ServiceCall<MessageResponse> response = conversationService.message(workspaceId, messageRequestBuilder.build());
        MessageResponse mAnswer =  response.execute();

        Object textObject = mAnswer.getOutput().get("text");
```

Comment: the problem is  always showing "dialog_turn_counter": 1.0, its not increasing

Comment: it's because you need to set the conversation_id in every sent.

Comment: can you tell me how i can set conversation id in my code because on every watson reply its send new conversation id in context